# What is the difference between creating instance by extending superclass and by extending its own class?

Tags: java

For example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

vs

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

What is the exact difference between these two?

When should we use the first one and when should we use the second?

Comment: Program to interface, not implementation

Comment: Neither of these are valid syntax - please give some *real* code we can compare. EDIT: Ah, it seems the question was asked mostly-correctly, but then other editors decided that `()` and `<>` were equivalent. They're not. I've fixed the question to make sense now.

Comment: Hi Jon , could you give me an example and detail explanation about this question?

Comment: Terminology: in neither of the examples you are 'extending' anything. The left hand side is the 'declaration' of the variable, the right hand side is the 'assignment' of a value to it. The first assignment of a variable is usually called its 'initialization'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first form is the most desirable one because you hide the implementation (ArrayList) from the rest of your code and ensure your code only works with the abstraction (List). The advantage of this is that your code will be more generic and therefore easier to adapt, for example when you change from using an ArrayList to a LinkedList, Vector or own List implementation. It also means local changes are less likely to cause changes in other parts of your code ('ripple-effect'), increasing your code's maintainability.

You need the second form when you want to do things with your variable that are not offered by the List interface, for example [ensureCapacity](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity%28int%29) or [trimToSize](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize%28%29)

EDIT: extra explanation of changing the implementation

Here is an example of declaring a variable as a [Collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) (an even more generic interface in java.util):

```
public class Example {

    private Collection<String> greetings = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void addGreeting(String greeting) {
        greetings.add(greeting);
    }
}
```

Now suppose you want to change the implementation in order to store unique greetings, and therefore switch from [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to [HashSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). Both are implementations of the Collection interface. This would be easy in this case because all the existing code treats the greetings field as a Collection:

```
public class Example {

    private Collection<String> greetings = new HashSet<String>();

    public void addGreeting(String greeting) {
        greetings.add(greeting);
    }
}
```

There is an exception. If there is code which casts the greetings field back to its implementation, this makes that code 'implementation-aware', violating the information-hiding you tried to achieve, for example:

```
ArrayList<String> greetingList = (ArrayList<String>) greetings;
greetingList.ensureCapacity(42);
```

Such code would cause a runtime error 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet incompatible with java.util.ArrayList' if you change the implementation to HashSet, so this practice should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Hi, I could not understand this line " for example when you change from using an ArrayList to a LinkedList, Vector or own List implementation".

Answer (score 5):

Use the first form whenever possible (I would even say: use `Collection` if sufficient). This is especially important when accepting input from client code (method arguments). Sometimes, for the convenience of the client code/library user it is better to accept the most generic input you can (like `Collection`) and deal with it rather than forcing the user to convert arguments all the time (user has `LinkedList` but the API requires `ArrayList` - terrible).

Use the second form only when you need to invoke methods on `list` variable that are defined in `ArrayList` but not in `List` (like [`ArrayList.trimToSize()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize%28%29)). Also when returning data to the user consider (but this is not the rule of thumb) returning more specific types. E.g. consider `List` over `Collection` so the client code can easier deal with the result. However! Returning too specific types (e.g. `ArrayList`) will lock your implementation for the future, so try to find a compromise.

This is a general rule - use the most general type you can. Even more general: use common sense.

Answer (score 3):

List is not a superclass, it is an interface.
By using List rather than ArrayList, you make sure that users of your list will only use methods that are defined on List. Meaning that you can change the implementation to (for example) Vector, without breaking the existing code.

So, use the first form.

Answer (score 0):

There are some advantages of using interfaces against concrete classes:

1. You are not stuck to concrete implementation (you can easy change it without modifying code)
2. Your code is clearer as no methods of concrete class are available

You need concrete implementation only in case if you USE some features of it. 
E.g. we have Matrix interface and have two concrete implementations SparseMathix and FullMatrix. If you want to effectively multiply them you CAN use some implementation details of SparseMatrix otherwise performance MAY be too slow.